# Is it correct to have this code in the main method stand alone as it's own class?

Tags: java, object, program-entry-point

[I'm taking this Java class online](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/creating-answers.html) and one of the questions asks the user to test playing card and deck classes.

I was writing my code in the main method of the Deck class, but peeked at the answer because I needed help. The tutorial has the code in the main method of a new class called DisplayDeck.

Does it make sense to have DisplayDeck stand alone as its own class?

```
public class DisplayDeck {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    for (int suit = Card.DIAMONDS; suit <= Card.SPADES; suit++) {
        for (int rank = Card.ACE; rank <= Card.KING; rank++) {
            Card card = deck.getCard(suit, rank);
            System.out.format("%s of %s%n",
                card.rankToString(card.getRank()),
                card.suitToString(card.getSuit()));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your arguments against it?

Comment: The answer, depends.  If your program is 1- small and 2- doesn't, in of itself, define functionality that you might like to extend in the future, then it should be a problem.  The more complex your program becomes, the more you will want to move out of the `main` method and allow other classes to take over - IMHO. From your description, a `Deck` has a specific purpose and it might be useful to re-use it in the future. Having a separate `main` class in this case may not be a bad idea

Comment: Since this is from a guided tutorial, there is probably a teaching reason the developers of the tutorial chose to do things that way that will become apparent when you are further along in the tutorial.

Comment: When they say to "create a deck of cards and display its cards", this sounds to me logic that would belong with the Deck class. I don't see how DisplayDeck can be used an object.

Comment: What if you are at a casino and  the dealer is using six decks?

Comment: @StacyM The logical representation of a deck of cards is display-agnostic, e.g., it could be presented as text, as graphics, as musical notes.

Comment: @bogeyc, maybe my understanding of OO is off...I would think your situation would be covered within the Deck class. DisplayDeck seems like functionality to me, not something that follows the Bicycle - MountainBike - ChildrensBike - RacingBike model...

Comment: "Functionality" can also be wrappedup in classes (and doing so makes things more flexible, and easier to test, although it can bring additional complexity). Objects don't have to represent physical entities, they can be things like TextDeckDisplayer.

Comment: Just being rhetorical. If all the DisplayDeck class is doing is displaying one deck, it may seem extraneous. But what if the DisplayDeck class was expanded into a Dealer class, which has characteristics and behaviors of displaying the deck, but also beyond that, like collecting bets, paying winners, etc? I think the tutorial is trying to ease you into OO and if you are familiar with OO from other languages may seem odd.

Comment: @bogeyc, a Dealer class being able to display the deck makes much more sense.

Comment: If it compiles and executes, it's correct. You're just asking an opinion-based stylistic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java everything needs to be in a class. When you "run" a program, you tell Java to load a class and call its `main()` method.

In this case, the only thing the program does is display the deck, so while making a `Deck` class with a `display()` method is conceptually clearer, it might be extraneous for the present purposes.

Think of `DisplayDeck` as a class representing not a deck of cards, but the program itself - this little program which spits out text and pretends to display a deck of cards. Java teaching code often has situations like this, e.g. a `HelloWorld` class. What is a `HelloWorld`?  I don’t know, but you’ve gotta have one in order to say hello (i.e., load the class and call its `main()` method).